# Intervals that are open sets in $Y=[0,4)$ as a topological subspace of ℝ with the upper limit topology

Tags: general-topology

The interval $(1,2)$ is open in the subspace topology because $(1,2)=(1,2)\cap Y$ and $(1,2)$ is in an open set in the upper limit topology.

The interval $[1,2]$ is open in the subspace topology because $[1,2]=(0,3)\cap Y$ and $(0,3)$ is in an open set in the upper limit topology.

I also believe $[0,3)$ is also open in the subspace topology, but not exactly sure why. Advice on why (maybe by the same logic as above?), and if my first two examples are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s true that $(1,2)$ is open in the upper limit topology on $\Bbb R$, though this does require a demonstration:

$$(1,2)=\bigcup_{1<x<2}(1,x]\;,$$

so $(1,2)$ is indeed a union of basic open sets in the upper limit topology and is therefore open.

$(0,3)$ is open in $Y$ for a similar reason, but $[1,2]$ is not: it does not contain any open nbhd of $1$.

$[0,3)=Y\cap(-1,3)$, and $(-1,3)$ is open in the upper limit topology on $\Bbb R$ (by the same kind of argument that I used to show that $(1,2)$ is), so $[0,3)$ is an open subset of $Y$ in the subspace topology. Unlike $(1,2)$ and $(0,3)$, however, $[0,3)$ is *not* open in the upper limit topology on $\Bbb R$, because it contains no open nbhd of $0$: every open nbhd of $0$ must contain a basic open nbhd of the form $(a,0]$ for some $a<0$.

**Exercise:** $Y$ has one isolated point in the subspace topology that it inherits from $\Bbb R$ with the upper limit topology; can you find it?